# Get content of div including input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, input

I'm replacing some specific character by inputs via regexp.

Div looks like that:

1) `<div>Text text text text <input> text text <input> text</div>`

2) `<div>text Text <input> text <input> text text Text</div>`

Is it possible to get whole text including input values from a div (with id 'body' in my case)?

jQuery code:

```
var body = data.body.replace(/\.\.\./g, "<input class='bodyy' type='text' size='2' />");
$("#body").html(body);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uepf87fc/

Comment: Don't. Use a parser instead.

Comment: In what format? Array, Object? Do you want the strings concatenated? What have you tried?

Comment: Which Parser? I just want to get text from div including input values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse it yourself with a function, here's an example:

```
function getTextWithInputValues(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!element) {
        return null;
    }

    var elementText = element.innerHTML; // Get the entire text from your element

    var elementInputs = element.getElementsByTagName('input'); // fetch all inputs from your element

    // replace all input fields with their respective values
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(elementInputs).forEach(
        (input) => {
            var inputText = elementInputs[input].outerHTML;
            if (elementText.search(inputText) > 0) {
                elementText = elementText.replace(inputText, elementInputs[input].value);
            }
        }
    );

    return elementText;

}
```

You can test it right here by opening a console, paste this code in, then type in something in the search box on the top of the page (don't click search, just type in something), then when you call the function in the console like `getTextWithInputValues('search')` it will output something like

```
<svg ......</svg>
your-text-here
<button .....</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh my god!! U are so good programator!!! Thank you! U saved my day!! Big respect!

Answer (score -1):

Even though you asked for `REGEX`, I don't believe it is by any means needed.

This will return the data in an array. With the first index being the body text, and each input field value thereafter.

```
var values = [];
values.push($('#body').text());

var inputs = $('#body input');

for(var i = 0; i < $(inputs).length; i++)
{
    var currentElement = $(inputs)[i];
    values.push($(currentElement).val());
}


console.log(values);
```

Comment: Well, that is a good idea, but I need input values exactly in the right place inside text.

Comment: Would have been nice to have mentioned that in your question. :|

Comment: I will try connect your solution with my solution. $("#body").html() and then again change '<input>' via regex to array values of inputs from your solution.